# mean_validation_score gives an AttributeError

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I am currently doing some exercises with Kernel Density Estimation and I am trying to run this piece of code:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

digits = load_digits()

bandwidths = 10 ** np.linspace(0, 2, 100)
grid = GridSearchCV(KDEClassifier(), {'bandwidth': bandwidths}, cv=3)
grid.fit(digits.data, digits.target)

scores = [val.mean_validation_score for val in grid.cv_results_]
```

but as the title says I get an

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-15a5f685e6d6> in <module>
      8 grid.fit(digits.data, digits.target)
      9 
---> 10 scores = [val.mean_validation_score for val in grid.cv_results_] 

<ipython-input-29-15a5f685e6d6> in <listcomp>(.0)
      8 grid.fit(digits.data, digits.target)
      9 
---> 10 scores = [val.mean_validation_score for val in grid.cv_results_] 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mean_validation_score'
```

regarding mean_validation_score and I don't understand why. The code is directly out of a book with a few changes due running an up to date scikit learn package. Here is the original code snipet:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV

digits = load_digits()

bandwidths = 10 ** np.linspace(0, 2, 100)
grid = GridSearchCV(KDEClassifier(), {'bandwidth': bandwidths})
grid.fit(digits.data, digits.target)

scores = [val.mean_validation_score for val in grid.grid_scores_]
```

EDIT:

Forgot to add how bandwiths is defined:

```py
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin


class KDEClassifier(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
    """Bayesian generative classification based on KDE

    Parameters
    ----------
    bandwidth : float
        the kernel bandwidth within each class
    kernel : str
        the kernel name, passed to KernelDensity
    """
    def __init__(self, bandwidth=1.0, kernel='gaussian'):
        self.bandwidth = bandwidth
        self.kernel = kernel

    def fit(self, X, y):
        self.classes_ = np.sort(np.unique(y))
        training_sets = [X[y == yi] for yi in self.classes_]
        self.models_ = [KernelDensity(bandwidth=self.bandwidth,
                                        kernel=self.kernel).fit(Xi)
                        for Xi in training_sets]
        self.logpriors_ = [np.log(Xi.shape[0] / X.shape[0])
                            for Xi in training_sets]
        return self

    def predict_proba(self, X):
        logprobs = np.array([model.score_samples(X)
                                for model in self.models_]).T
        result = np.exp(logprobs + self.logpriors_)
        return result / result.sum(1, keepdims=True)

    def predict(self, X):
        return self.classes_[np.argmax(self.predict_proba(X), 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, I also face the same problem, Just replace this line-

```
scores = [val.mean_test_score for val in grid.cv_results_]
```

with

```
scores = grid.cv_results_.get('mean_test_score').tolist()
```

Because, 'mean_test_score' is depricated and grid.cv_results_ is in dict format.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) of the object `GridSearchCV` specifies that the attribute `cv_results_` is a dictionary, therefore, iterating over a python dictionary returns the strings of the keys as you can se [here](https://realpython.com/iterate-through-dictionary-python/).

My recommendation is to specify at the `GridSearchCV` constructor the `scoring` you want to use and then have a look at the `cv_results_` dictionary.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand your recommendation. But many thanks anyway.